# The cyclic group generated by the product of generators of two cyclic subgroups.

Tags: group-theory

Let $P=(a)$ and $Q=(b)$ be cyclic subgroups of a group $G$ with intersection of $P$ and $Q$ being $(e)$. Then $O(ab)=pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are prime orders of $P$ and $Q$ respectively. But I cannot figure out how. Any help will be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't $G$ need to be abelian?

Comment: i guess not. The original problem was, let G be a group of order pq where p and q are primes. p less than q and p does not divide q-1. show that G has a unique p-sylow subgroup and a unique q-sylow subgroup. then show that G is cyclic

Comment: It's not even true in the abelian case when $p=q$. In the nonabelian it's not always true even when $p \ne q$. For any integers $l,m,n >1$ there are examples with $O(a)=l$, $O(b)=m$, $O(ab)=n$.

Comment: thank you... but is it not true for primes? since intersection of P and Q is (e) we have ab=ba. Also O(a)=p and O(b)=q. I had tutorial question asking to prove O(ab)=pq given these data. group theory is really confusing for me.

Comment: It is not necessarily true that $ab=ba$.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false. For example, take

$$P=\langle (12)\rangle\;,\;\;Q=\langle (123)\rangle \le S_3$$

Here, we have that

$$|P|=2\;,\;\;|Q|=3\;,\;\;P\cap Q=1\;,\;\;\text{yet}\;\;(12)(123)=(23)\;\;\text{has order}\;\;2\neq 6=2\cdot 3$$